# How to create tables in SQL which are participating in inheritance

Tags: sql, inheritance, ddl

I am a beginner in SQL. I am ambiguous about how to create tables in SQL code which participate in inheritance. Is it done the same way as normal tables or is there any special approach?

I have customer and staff tables which are child tables of person table. Both have some common features and some distinct features. Please help me.

Comment: Sql is more about entities than inheritance Venkat. I'd store the main data in the person table and then have the specific fields in the other tables. Alternatively I'd have a flag for customer and staff in the person table and store the object as json.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can proceed with my assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Hibernate documentation explains available approaches even if you don't care about ORM: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance. In summary:

- Share programming language code but have completely unrelated tables
  on DB
- Use one table with all possible columns and a discriminator
  that says how the row should be implemented
- One table with common
  columns and separate table for each "child" table.